# Wordpress dequeued script is still showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to dequeue an admin script:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_admin_script', 100);
function remove_admin_script() {
    wp_dequeue_script('layers-admin');
}
```

This script here returns a list of the handles for all the scripts on the page:

```
function wpa54064_inspect_scripts() {
global $wp_scripts;
foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
    echo $handle . ' | ';
endforeach;
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa54064_inspect_scripts' );
```

When I dequeue my script, I can see from my list of handles that it is no longer there, however, in my source code it still shows.

Can anyone tell me why my script isn't removing?

Here is how the scripts are called from the plugin i'm trying to remove them from:

```
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts' , 'layers_admin_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' , 'layers_admin_scripts' );
```

Here is the whole script from the theme that enqueues the script I'm trying to remove (admin.js)

```
if( ! function_exists( 'layers_admin_scripts' ) ) {
function layers_admin_scripts(){
    global $pagenow, $wp_customize;

    wp_enqueue_style(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-tip-tip' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/tipTip.css',
        array(),
        LAYERS_VERSION
    ); // Tip-Tip CSS

    wp_enqueue_style(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-font-awesome',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/font-awesome.min.css',
        array(),
        LAYERS_VERSION
    ); // Inline Editor

    wp_enqueue_style(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/admin.css',
        array(),
        LAYERS_VERSION
    ); // Admin CSS

    wp_enqueue_style(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-editor',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/editor.css',
        array(),
        LAYERS_VERSION
    ); // Inline Editor

    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-tip-tip' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/jquery.tipTip.minified.js',
        array(
            'jquery',
        ),
        LAYERS_VERSION,
        true
    ); // Tip-Tip JS

    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-editor' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/editor.min.js' ,
        array( 'jquery' ),
        LAYERS_VERSION,
        true
    ); // Inline Editor

    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-migrator' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/migrator.js' ,
        array(
            'media-upload'
        ),
        LAYERS_VERSION,
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-media-views' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/media-views.js',
        array(
            'media-views'
        ),
        LAYERS_VERSION
    ); // Discover More Photos

    wp_localize_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-migrator',
        'migratori18n',
        array(
            'loading_message' => __( 'Be patient while we import the widget data and images.' , 'layerswp' ),
            'complete_message' => __( 'Import Complete' , 'layerswp' ),
            'importing_message' => __( 'Importing Your Content' , 'layerswp' ),
            'duplicate_complete_message' => __( 'Edit Your New Page' , 'layerswp' )
        )
    );// Migrator// Localize Scripts
    wp_localize_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-migrator',
        "layers_migrator_params",
        array(
                'duplicate_layout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-migrator-duplicate' ),
                'import_layout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-migrator-import' ),
                'preset_layout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-migrator-preset-layouts' ),
            )
    );

    // Onboarding Process
    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-onboarding' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/onboarding.js',
        array(
                'jquery'
            ),
        LAYERS_VERSION,
        true
    ); // Onboarding JS

    wp_localize_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-onboarding' ,
        "layers_onboarding_params",
        array(
            'preset_layout_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-migrator-preset-layouts' ),
            'update_option_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-onboarding-update-options' ),
            'set_theme_mod_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-onboarding-set-theme-mods' ),
        )
    ); // Onboarding ajax parameters

    wp_localize_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin-onboarding' ,
        'onboardingi18n',
        array(
            'step_saving_message' => __( 'Saving...' , 'layerswp' ),
            'step_done_message' => __( 'Done!' , 'layerswp' )
        )
    ); // Onboarding localization

    wp_enqueue_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin' ,
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/assets/admin.js',
        array(
            'jquery',
            'jquery-ui-sortable',
            'wp-color-picker',
        ),
        LAYERS_VERSION,
        true
    ); // Admin JS

    wp_localize_script(
        LAYERS_THEME_SLUG . '-admin' ,
        "layers_admin_params",
        array(
            'backup_pages_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'layers-backup-pages' ),
            'backup_pages_success_message' => __('Your pages have been successfully backed up!', 'layerswp' )
        )
    ); // Onboarding ajax parameters

    wp_enqueue_media();

}
}

add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts' , 'layers_admin_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts' , 'layers_admin_scripts' );
```

or here's a link to the whole file on Git:
https://github.com/Obox/layerswp/blob/master/functions.php

The files are called from a theme called layers and are only called in the wordpress customizer

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_admin_script', 100 );
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts' , 'remove_admin_script', 100 );
```

Would be more correct than running a function after wp_print_scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question though, I'm trying to dequeue an admin script - this function that you have corrected just shows me the handle for the scripts that are being enqueued

Comment: ah well you never mentioned admin, what i was giving you was the correct place to run your dequeue function, the normal priority is 10, so 100 should be after whatever function attached to enqueue the script.  if you run this after the script has been output, its too late if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks @David - that does make perfect sense, unfortunately it doesn't work for me though - I've tried pretty much every solution I can find about dequeing scripts and nothing works, so I'm starting to think this can't be done

Comment: it can be done alright, what is the actual code of the function that adds the script? where is it added, in the header/footer? its not hard coded ? also there is a technique for caching header output, i assume caching is not a issue?

Comment: Hi @David, updated my answer to show the scripts used to call the file i'm trying to remove